# Spring AOP failure on startup: NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.OrderUtils.getOrder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I have an Aspect with a pointcut within all RestController annotated controllers:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ControllerLoggingAspect {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void controller() {
    }

    @Before("controller()")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("START REST CONTROLLER");
    }

    @After("controller()")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("END REST CONTROLLER");
    }
}
```

pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error in the log:
`NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.OrderUtils.getOrder`

I can verify that I do have the `OrderUtils` class with the `getOrder` method in my project.

If I remove the `@Before` and `@After` annotated methods, Spring starts up with no errors.

Does anyone have an idea on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my the versions between my `spring-aop` and `spring-core` dependencies differed. Fixing them to match caused AOP to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make AOP class for after annotation:

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class AfterAopAspect {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.alok.*.*(..))", returning = "result")
    public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        logger.info("{} returned with value {}", joinPoint, result);
    }

    @After(value = "execution(* com.alok.*.*(..))")
    public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.info("after execution of {}", joinPoint);
    }
}
```